# c# - Trying to capture screen using bitmap

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bitmap

I'm using windows Forms app in visual studio 2019. Never really used c# besides this but i'm trying to display the color of the pixel in the mouse coordinates.
However the rgb always equals 0 for all.

```
public static Point GetMousePositionWindowsForms()
{
    System.Drawing.Point point = Control.MousePosition;
    return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
}

public static string Getcolor()
{
    Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Color getcolor = screen.GetPixel(GetMousePositionWindowsForms().X-1, GetMousePositionWindowsForms().Y-1);
    return Convert.ToString(getcolor);
}
```

Comment: Any reason for `GetMousePositionWindowsForms` ?

Comment: The reason for the GetMousePositionWindowsForms is to get the mouse coordinates.

Comment: You're creating a new bitmap with the dimensions of the screen, but not taking a screenshot.

Comment: It simply returns `Control.MousePosition`, doesn't it? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must capture the screen before getting color. Try this:

```
public static string Getcolor()
{
    Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics captureGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screen);
    captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height));
    Color getcolor = screen.GetPixel(GetMousePositionWindowsForms().X-1, GetMousePositionWindowsForms().Y-1);
    return Convert.ToString(getcolor);
}
```